# How acceptable are self-citations?

Tags: citations, ethics

How acceptable are self-citations? I noticed that my advisor cites his own work quite much, even when the cited articles are not directly related, e.g. type of analysed data is different. Actually, I did not notice this myself - it was pointed out by a reviewer (I authored my first paper with him just now). Looking at his citation records, I found out that he has papers with about 15 citations, of which about ~10 are typically from himself. Our field existed before my grandmother was born, so I'm a little alerted.. This puts the offer to do a PhD with himself to a new light.